# Does networkx.all_simple_paths() generate the same ordered paths every time we call it?

Tags: python, networkx

I needed to get all simple paths at different places, and I want whenever I call netowrkx.all_simple_paths(), it will return the same ordered paths, since this is very important in my use case.

So, is this guaranteed by this function?

Comment: It probably does (in the sense that python dicts generally return in a consistent order), but if you make any changes to your graph, I would expect that it doesn't.  To be safe, can you just save a list of the paths?

Comment: I realize this problem after I almost finish my coding, it will be a lot of work if I want to refactor. So if the order are consistent, I can just use my code for now. I may consider use list to store the paths in the future coding.